# How can i select table thread order by popular thread in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relation

i really confuse at eloquent that used for selecting popular thread when popular parameter was exist at difference table, so my table look like bellow:

```
-------------------
|    thread        |
-------------------
|id (int)          |
|title (varchar)   |
|value (text)      |
|timestamp         |
-------------------

 -------------------
|    comment       |
-------------------
|id (int)          |
|value (text)      |
|id_thread (id)    |
|timestamp         |
-------------------
```

so with above table, i wanna show all thread that order by most commented thread using eloquent laravel.
i spend much time at this cases, but doesnt got sollution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$tops = Thread::join('comments', 'comments.id_thread', '=', 'threads.id')
->select(
    'thread.*', 
    DB::raw('count(comments.id) as total_comments')
)->orderBy('total_comments', 'desc')
->groupBy('threads.id') // or 'id'
->take(10) //top 10 ?
->get();
```

You may come across an error related to GROUPBY saying stuff like "...because it is not contained in a grouby". It means you have to groupBy that column. Every column that shows that error, add it in the group by.

Comment: its still show error, 
`Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'thread.id' isn't in GROUP BY` .
much query that i try, always show like this. iam stuck here

Comment: You didnt pay attention to my comment next to the group by. I update the code for you. And I warned you might see those error. Simply add the column to the groupBy, separated by a comma `groupBy('column1', 'column2')`

Comment: oh snap, i am sorry didnt notice that warn. finally its solved, thank you very much sir.

Comment: Please, mark my answer then since it's working. Thanks :)